# Database manage in Ruby project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migration

I've some question. Me with my team are implementing an application in Ruby and Rails. It is my first Ruby project and I'm wonder how to manage database changes. For example at the beginning I will create DB schema and I should create dump for all team members which everyone could import db schema localy or rather create migrations and all manage for their (no dumps).

- Are migrations used only for DB changes??
- Can we use migrations to setup db schema localy??
- What are the trends ??

Thanks for all answers

Comment: Question is not specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are migrations used only for DB changes??

Answer: Yes migration are used to manage operation on the database but the migration are also used to create a database with the if you do not have created datebase. just run a single command `rake db:migrate` and that will update schema.rb file and created database on specified server in your yml file.

Can we use migrations to setup db schema localy??

Answer: Yes you can.

What are the trends ??

Answers: Every time if you wants to make any changes in database you have to create a migration for that and have to write the up and down methods and table and column information.

one more thing

`rake db:migrate` command will run all the migration which you have in your /db/migrate folder

and if you wants to run one of them then use below command.

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=your new migration number
```